# Show that $(\mathbb{R}^n,||\cdot||_2)^*=(\mathbb{R}^n,||\cdot||_2)$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I want to show that $(\mathbb{R}^n,||\cdot||_2)^*=(\mathbb{R}^n,||\cdot||_2)$.

So far I know that $$\langle Ax,y\rangle=(Ax)^Ty=x^TA^Ty=x^T(A^Ty)=\langle x,A^Ty\rangle.$$

Could you give a simple example that shows that the the equality $(\mathbb{R}^n,||\cdot||_2)^*=(\mathbb{R}^n,||\cdot||_2)$ holds?

Comment: $(\mathbb R^n, \|\cdot\|_2)^*$ denotes the dual of the vector space. Which kind of matrices are used to describe linear maps from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$?

Comment: HInt: Every functional in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is of the form $f(x)=\langle a,x\rangle$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Roland, are those column matrices?

Comment: @Forest: These matrices have $1$ row and $n$ columns - if that's what you mean with column matrices.

Comment: @Roland: No, but it makes more sense. So every element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ maps to an element of $\mathbb{R}$, creating a vector?

Comment: Would it be enough to say this: if $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then exists $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ that $f(x)=a^Tx$. Taking the Euclidean norm, $|f(x)|=|\sum_{1}^{n}a_jx_j|\leq (\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j^2)^{1/2}(\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j^2)^{1/2}=||a|| ||x||$
and since $f(a)=||a|| ||a||$ we get $||f||=||a||_2$

Comment: Almost. We need to show that there's an $x$  with  $\|x\|=1$ such that $|f(x)| = \|a\|$, i.e. $x= \frac{a}{\|a\|}$ is a good candidate for showing this.

Comment: And how could I do that?